# AWS S3 Storage put method

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi I have an AWS S3 bucket I added the storage using amplify add storage. I can pull images from the public folder I made, for some reason though I can not put/add images. I want to specify the folder public/ when I run the put. I get a forbidden error (`SignatureDoesNotMatch`) right now might just be because I am not specifying the public folder or my permissions is not setup properly. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
const uploadedImage = await Storage.put(imgsPreview[0].img)
```

Comment: "folder public/ when I run the put" - this is a terrible security issue. You should never need to make your bucket public for anonymous uploads. Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const uploadedImage = await Storage.put(`${some_loaction}/${imgsPreview[0].img.name}`,imgsPreview[0].img, { contentType: "image/*" })
```

You alsoe can rename the file `${imgsPreview[0].img.name}`. You can use uuid

```
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";

const uploadedImage = await Storage.put(`${some_loaction}/${uuid()}${imgsPreview[0].img.name.split(".").pop()}`,imgsPreview[0].img, { contentType: "image/*" })
```

So finally you can get you image under public/some_loaction/Your_file_name